# Cursor in Linked List changing value for no apparent reason

Tags: c++, singly-linked-list

***Edit***

***For simplicity:*** I just want to make the most basic possible cursor that simply goes trough my list without changing in any way / shape or form my "begin". I still want begin to be changed when I return something though, just not before. So is it possible to make a pointer to begin, go trough the list without changing anything except at the very end when I want to add a new node ?

***Also*** Can I just go trough the list with a simple pointer that is not a "Node" ?

***/Edit***

I have a simple (singly) linked list to make as part of my homework. Of-course I also have a lot to do besides that, but after I get the list out of the way everything should be strait forward, but while I have been using C++ for a while (it was borland C++) a lot of what I knew is either half-forgotten or outdated. I have programmed in python for a while but all that means is that I keep getting frustrated with how pointers work in C++.

My problem is when I try to add a new Node to the list, my cursor behaves in an unusual manner, I will explain below:

***EDIT:*** Ok, I changed the:

```
Node *cursor;
cursor = new Node
cursor = begin;
```

fiasco, but the result is the same, after the declaration cursor and begin both point at the same memory location (something like: 0x32ce8).

***/EDIT***

```
Node *add_node (Node *begin,string type, int sum, int ap_nr) // begin is the first node in the list
{
    // if first node is dummy node

    if (begin->ap_nr == -1)
        {
            begin->type = type;
            begin->ap_nr = ap_nr;
            begin->sum = sum;
            begin->next = 0;
            return begin;
        }

    // else create new node and insert it in sorted position

   else
    {
        // EDIT:
        Node *cursor = begin; // Same problem

        //if node should be inserted before first node (begin)

        if (ap_nr <begin->ap_nr)
        {
            cursor->ap_nr = ap_nr;
            cursor->type = type;
            cursor->sum = sum;
            cursor->next = begin;
            return cursor;
        }
```

Always when I debug, begin has a similar form: 0x32ce02, when I create my "cursor" it has a vastly different form (longer also), but when I do this : cursor = begin, then cursor becomes something like this 0x32df02.

However the problem is when I get to "if (ap_nr ap_nr)" then for absolutely no feasible reason cursor becomes: 0x32ce02 and "cursor -> next = begin" ensures an infinite loop. And no matter how many nodes I add this always happens so whenever I print the list it's an infinite stream of the last added Node.

Am I doing something wrong ? is it the declaration or the alocation, creation ? something ?

Also if I have a pointer *begin somewhere in another module, and with this function I return a new begin ... that should work, right ?

P.S. I would also appreciate a simple counter solution (another way to do this if mine is just not good)

Also I should point out how I made my list. It is just a simple linking of nodes:

```
struct Node {
    string type;
    int ap_nr;
    int sum;
    Node *next;
};
```

Comment: it doesn't actually, that happens later. But what I would like to do is create a very simple cursor that starts from begin. If there is an easier way of doing that I would rather get that answer instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pointers `cursor` and `begin` point to the same memory location because you explicitly say so: `Node* cursor = begin;` *literally* says "create a pointer variable named `cursor` which points to the same location as `begin`." So it is no surprise that it does.

**Edit:** Removed advice based on a wrong guess what the code is intended to do and changed it to more applicable advice

From the comment, I now understand that you want to insert a node at a position so that the field `ap_nr` is increasing in the resulting list, assuming it is increasing originally (if that still isn't right, please state clearly what you *do* want).

For that case, the initialization of `cursor` is of course now correct. However it is *not* correct to modify the object `cursor` points to: You want to insert a *new* node *before* that node. But for that you have to make several changes:

First, you need *another* pointer variable, which holds a pointer to a newly created node, like

```
Node* new_node = new Node;
```

And then you have to insert *that* node into the list. That is, instead of `cursor->ap_nr=ap_nr;` etc. you have to use `new_node->ap_nr=ap_nr;` etc. Also, the node following it is of course *not* the first node of the list (pointed to by `first`) but the one you just found (pointed to by `current`).

However, now you have a problem: You have to insert that new node into the list, which means you have to modify the `next` pointer of the *previous* node (but to point not to `begin`, but to the newly created node!). But you don't have any more the pointer to the previous node, because your list is singly-linked, that is, you don't have a pointer from the found element to the previous element. But to insert the element, you *have* to change the `next`.

However what you *do* have is a pointer to the *next* node. Therefore a better strategy is to have your `cursor` point to the *previous* node, and then consistently use `cursor->next` instead of `cursor` (except when moving `cursor`, of course). That way you can, *after* you've set `new_node->next`, write `cursor->next = new_node;`

Other things which are missing from your code are checks that `current` is not null (which it will be at the end of the list) and ther code acrtually moving your `cursor` forward (which belongs into an `else` part of your inner `if`).

Actually I now notice that your blocks are not closed, so the moving-forward code might be there in your actual code.

At the end, some general advice: You probably would have an easier time writing that code if you modularized the code of your function: Have one function to insert a new node after a given one (changing only the `next` pointers, and returning a pointer to the newly inserted code), have *another* function to find the node after which the new node should be inserted, and have your function `add_node` only call those other functions. That way, in each function you can concentrate on one of the sub-problems.

Comment: I just want to make a simple cursor to go trough my list and use that cursor as a reference point without damaging, changing or even scratching begin. I only want to modify begin when I return a Node.

Comment: But then how do I go trough the list then ? if `Node* cursor = new Node;` ?

Comment: OK, since you never change `cursor` after creating it (and setting it to `begin`) I wouldn't have guessed it. In that case, your initialization is of course right, but you have problems in the rest of your code. I'll update my answer to reflect that, since I now (think I) understand what you want.

Comment: Ok, this is exactly what I wanted, I am sorry my english is OK but it isn't good enough to explain things related to programming or math or anything that could be considered a school subject or work related. And yes, the function is actually much longer. I did think of modularizing it, but I was more focused on this bit that has proven to be a head-ache .

Answer (score 2):

This code:

```
cursor = new Node;
cursor = begin;
```

Does the following:

- Create a new Node object on the stack
- Put the address of that object in variable `current`
- Immediately overwrite that address with the address that `begin` contains

i.e. all it does is leak a new `Node`. `cursor` and `begin` point to the same thing after that.

Thus the line:

```
cursor->next = begin;
```

Makes a loop. `cursor->next == begin == cursor`.

Removing the `cursor = begin;` line, and returning cursor will do what you want. The Node created with `new Node` will be the new head of the list, and the one that `begin` pointed to at the start of the function will be the second node in that list.

Now when you want to traverse (not add to) that list, you can do something like:

```
 Node *cursor = begin; // assuming begin is the head of your list
 while (cursor != 0) {
    // process this node
    cursor = cursor->next;
 }
```

And that will visit each node in your list, assuming you've built it correctly.

A few notes:

- The code that calls this function should probably look something like:

  ```
  list = add_node(list, ...);
  ```

  If you don't have that, you'll not get what you want.
- If the address you see in `begin` looks *very* different from the one returned by `new`, you're could be doing something wrong, i.e. `begin` could point at a stack address. Don't put objects from your stack on the list, make sure you all allocate them with `new`. (If `begin` points to a global static variable, that's fine - but make sure you don't `delete` it).
- Unless you actually *need* a dummy node, I'd suggest you remove that too - it makes your `add_node` function more complex than it needs to be.

Here's a skeleton of how you would do it without that special dummy node (incomplete code):

```
Node *add_node(Node *list, ...)
{
  Node *new_node = new Node;
  new_node->next = list;
  // fill in other properties
  return new_node;
}
```

And to use this:

```
int foo()
{
    Node *list = 0; // or nullptr for C++11
    list = add_node(list, ...); // add item 1
    list = add_node(list, ...); // add item 2
    list = add_node(list, ...); // add item 3
    ...
```

Comment: I have added the way I make my list, and I am unsure if what you say is actually true ("The Node created with new Node will be the new head of the list, and the one that begin pointed to at the start of the function will be the second node in that list.") Maybe there is a way to do this, but the way I implemented it does not seem to be the case, how or what should I modify ... and why ? (I'd like to get a general idea of how it should work)

Comment: Ohhhh ok, I just missed something completely. Ok, now I understand, creating a new nod then `new_node = old_node` bleeds a node, but if I don't create one, I just declare and then `new_node = old_node` that should work. Ok, I'll try, thank you.

Comment: Ok, now all that happens is `Node *cursor = begin` simply overwrites it outright.

Comment: I don't understand your comments. Yes, `Node *cursor = begin` "overwrites" something. After that line, begin and cursor are synonyms, they point to the same thing. `cursor = cursor->next` makes cursor point to the next element (or nothing). `cursor = new Node` makes cursor point to a new, uninitialized node. I've added a bit more information, but I'm afraid I can't help you much more if you don't understand how these pointers work.

Comment: I do think I finally do, I also resolved the problem, mostly.

Answer (score 1):

```
    Node *cursor;
    cursor = new Node;
    cursor = begin;
```

Understand exactly what you are doing with these 3 lines here - there might be more going on than you actually realise.

- On the first line, you declare a new variable called *cursor* - this variable is a name for a pointer object which has a type of **Node***.  (in plain english, Node* means "pointer-to *Node*").
  The type of data stored in a pointer object is simply numeric integral data which happens to represent an address in memory.  a pointer object is really no different to any other kind of integer object.
  (Note the difference between "variable" and "object" - an object is something stored in memory, such as a number/a character/a memory address, and a variable is a ***name*** for an object)
- On the second line, two things happen - firstly you allocate memory for a **Node** object and construct a new **Node** object in that allocated memory - this memory does not have a variable name, it's just a free-store object (That's the short version of how *new Node* works), Then you use the = operator (assignment operator) to store the address value (a number) of the newly allocated **Node** object in your *cursor* variable.
  After storing the address value of the new Node object, the only way to access the newly allocated Node object is through the cursor variable name.
- On the third line, you immediately overwrite the value stored by your cursor variable; instead of storing the address data for the new Node, it stores the address of another object (The address of that other object copied from another pointer variable called *begin*).    This has the immediate effect of causing the newly allocated **Node** to be "Leaked".

The point which I am trying to put across (Which I believe you might not realise) is that there are potentially four distinct objects (i.e. "items in memory") to consider in those three lines of code.    Two of them are pointer objects (integers) called *cursor* and *begin*, the other two are free-store objects (Nodes) which have no name, but are accessible using the address values stored by your pointer objects.

There are a bunch of links which you might find worth reading here:

- http://www.eternallyconfuzzled.com/tuts/languages/jsw_tut_pointers.aspx
- http://www.augustcouncil.com/~tgibson/tutorial/ptr.html
- http://www.daweidesigns.com/cgi-bin/pointers.php
- http://www.c-faq.com/ptrs/index.html

Comment: Thank you, that was a very good answer, but I have already done some suggested modification to no avail. Hope it's not somewhere else in the program ... because of all my recent modifications to try and make this work it has become very convoluted and It's too much to post it here any way.